# Import Dll library in java

Tags: java, eclipse, dll, rfid

I have a Dll library that contain methods for changing the state of RFID reader , So how can I import the library to be able to use these methods in java ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to USE JNA "Java Native Access" its a library which provides easy access to native shared libraries. for example check the following link https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/GettingStarted.md

Comment: Note the blog pionts to the old location of JNA, new location is [here](https://github.com/twall/jna) which also includes a [getting started](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/GettingStarted.md) page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the dll file then use System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME) to load the library

Comment: But how can I use  methods that exist inside Dll library ?

Comment: well usually a library comes with documentation and guides that tells you on how to use it.